# Invalid Object Name dbo.TableName even when such a table exists in the DB

Tags: .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, windows-services

I got the following error while running a windows service in one of the environments in my project:

**Error Message:**

```
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
```

**Inner Exception Message:**

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.ProcessTracker'.
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

I have made sure that such a table exists in the database that the service is connecting to. Also, the same service is installed in other environments/servers and is working fine.

We are using EF 6 
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: One more additional information. I tried connecting to the same database running the service code(it's a topshelf service) from my local machine and got the same error. However, I used the same connection details to log into the db from SSMS and I found that the table is existing under the dbo. schema.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive the service is connecting to the correct database?

Comment: It might be a silly question to ask, but how do I ensure that the service is connecting to the database. It certainly is not loading any tables, but if it were unable to connect at all, wouldn't it have thrown an "unable to connect" exception at initialization itself?

Comment: Can you show the connection string you are using? You can try stopping the server and if the app still reports the same error, you know it's not trying to connect to the right place.

Comment: It's staging environment and prep work is going on for UAT. Lot of other teams are testing their components. So stopping server is out of scope. I will post the connection string shortly.

Comment: <add name="Fleet" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Fleet.csdl|res://*/Models.Fleet.ssdl|res://*/Models.Fleet.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=***DBSERVERNAME**;initial catalog=***DBNAME***;persist security info=True;user id=***USERID****;password=***PASSWORD***;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: connection string added above

Comment: Thanks, so the server is called DBSERVERNAME and the database is DBNAME (obviously replace with real values)? Next question is, are you sure the connection string name is correct, in other words, is the application looking for `Fleet`?

Comment: Yes, I checked that too. It is using the right name. Also, the same connection string is used in other envs, with just the servername, db name and creds changed. Nothing else is changed...

Comment: I got the connection string from the stage env from the deployment engineer. There is a small mistake in that (made while copy pasting). But even without that mistake, in my local it yeilds the same error when connecting to the staging database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71267/discussion-between-surjith-c-r-and-davidg).

Comment: @David- Finally I have update from the deloyment team. They redeployed after correcting the error and it started working. Like you pointed out, the application was probably not connecting to staged db from my local machine due to some other issue(firewall?)

Comment: @DavidG Thanks for your time. Sorry to have wasted it.

Answer (score 1):

Folks,

The issue turned out to be with the connection string in configuration file. There was an error in the config file which caused this issue.